# Maximum principles (weak, strong) for semi-linear parabolic equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

The scalar reaction-diffusion equation 
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)~~(*)
$$
with some non-linearity $f(u)$ is a semi-linear parabolic pde.

I know that for *linear* parabolic pde there are the weak maximum principle and the strong maximum principle, see here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle.

I guess these does, in general, not hold semi-linear parabolic pde as $(*)$?

Are there similar statements?